# how to clear a graphic object without using clear() method in c#?

Tags: c#

is it possible to clear the graphic object without a clear method?

Comment: what? could you supply more details please....

Comment: You should probably explain why you don't want to use the Clear method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use `FillRectangle` / `FillRegion`, but `Clear()` is the obvious choice here.